# Sequelize where condition as raw

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model defined. I would like to do an advanced select query in postgres on that model.

The raw query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    6371 * acos(
        cos(
            radians("+CustomerLat+")
        ) * cos(radians(sto.lat)) * cos(
            radians(sto.lng) - radians("+CustomerLng+")
        ) + sin(
            radians("+CustomerLat+")
        ) * sin(radians(sto.lat))
    ) AS distance
FROM
    stores sto
ORDER BY
    distance ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Could I do that with sequelize directly on the model without doing this in raw?

```
Stores
.findAll()
.then(function(res){ //****// })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is old but, There are two things I would suggest... Firstly why don't you use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) a postgresql extension which is superb and fast when it comes to GIS data. Secondly.. No! you can't do that... But for advanced **where clause** conditions I would suggest mixing things up with [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) A raw query builder. You can use [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) to build your **where clause** and mix things up with [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) to get the best results.